# How to dynamically remove key value pair from a dictionary if the key contains some substring?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have an outer loop iterating over an array of substrings to be matched in the dictionary. In the inner loop I want to iterate over the dictionary and delete an entry whose key contains a substring.How to do this without getting "Collection was modified Exception"?

```
foreach (string outerKey in new string[] { "PAYERADDR_PAYERNAME", "RECADDR_RECNAME", "PAYERADDR_ADDR", "RECADDR_ADDR" })
{
    foreach (var item in _generalWorksheetData.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(outerKey)).ToList())
        {
            _generalWorksheetData.Remove(item.Key);
        }
}
```

Comment: You're writing that you want to remove items that have a key that contains some string but in your code you're checking the values `kvp.Value.Contains(outerKey)` ;-) with your code you were almost there. It doesn't work because you're selecting the items of the dictionary here `kvp` (`KeyValuPair`) which you must not change if they are part of a loop. If you took the keys like `.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList()` it would have worked ;-]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a new collection:

```
List<string> todelete = dictionary.Keys.Where(k => k.Contains("substring")).ToList();
todelete.ForEach(k => dictionary.Remove(k));
```

or with a `foreach`:

```
foreach (string key in todelete)
    dictionary.Remove(key);  // safe to delete since it's a different collection
```

If [`Dictionary.Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6(v=vs.110).aspx) implemented `IList` instead of just `ICollection` you could access it in a backwards for-loop to remove them. But since there is no indexer you can't.

Comment: @PranayRana: actually `List.ForEach` is not the reason why it works but because i create a new list with `ToList`. As you can see now you can also use a plain `foreach`-loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't. However you can store those pairs in a list and delete them in a separate loop from the first.

Answer (score 1):

Find match and remove the entries as below

```
var keysWithMatchingValues = dictionary.Where(d => d.Key.Contains("xyz"))
                               .Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();

foreach(var key in keysWithMatchingValues)
    dictionary.Remove(key);
```

Comment: This doesn't compile since `dic` is a `KeyValuPair`, but even if you use `Remove(dic.Key)` it also  causes the Collection was modified exception which OP wants to prevent. The same happens if you use `dictionary.Keys.Where(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just update your inner `foreach` as following:

```
foreach (var item in _generalWorksheetData.Keys.Where(kvp => kvp.Contains(outerKey)).ToList())
   {
      _generalWorksheetData.Remove(item);
   }
```

Note that LINQ extension methods `ToList` and `ToArray` do allow you to modify collections.

```
        List<string> sampleList = new List<string>();
        sampleList.Add("1");
        sampleList.Add("2");
        sampleList.Add("3");
        sampleList.Add("4");
        sampleList.Add("5");

        // Will not work
        foreach (string item in sampleList)
        {
            sampleList.Remove(item);
        }

        // Will work
        foreach (string item in sampleList.ToList())
        {
            sampleList.Remove(item);
        }
```